# Saving image from Image object to isoStorage?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I've been googling around, and all the different answers has got me confused.

In my app I retrieve a contact picture, and put it in an Image object to be displayed to the user. 
But I want to save the image to isostorage, and later retrieve it again.

How do I do this?

Can I use the Image.Source for anything?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a filename or an ISO storage file.

The only use for ISO storage is to store a file of the bitmap and open a stream to that file to recreate a bitmap later.

The bitmap can then be assigned to the Image.Source.